# Node with Sails.js change hook behaviour OR create new blueprint

Tags: node.js, sails.js, json-rpc

In Sails.js the Rest blueprint is handled by the hooks on sails/lib/hooks/controller .
How can one change the hook behaviou or make a new bluePrint behaviour without medling with the core?

I want to make a JSON RPC 2.0 Hook and replace rest with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CRUD blueprint overriding in Sailsjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273789/crud-blueprint-overriding-in-sailsjs)

Comment: Thought it was a duplicate after seeing. But is not exactly what i need . As soon as i get the desired behaviour will post it here. The answer pointed me in the right direction