# Sails.js and Ember.js integration

Tags: ember.js, sails.js

Has anyone tried to use sails as ember's backend API?
How would you go about it?
Is there an example available?
Since Sails has a different format in its built-in blueprints, is it better to make sails rest json format confirm to what ember expects or the other way around?

Thanks!

**Edit**

So there are two approaches:

1. change the sails format, maybe with: [CRUD blueprint overriding in sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273789/crud-blueprint-overriding-in-sailsjs)
2. change what ember expects: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/sails-js-as-the-backend/5233

Comment: Consider you backend API to use Ember-data's best practices, and there's no difference, which framework for Node you'll use.

Ember-data provides `RESTAdapter` which lets you write almost no code in such a case.

Comment: I wasn't clear maybe... sails provides a blueprint REST API with it's built-in format I want to use this wonderful feature of sails

Comment: A third option is to use the SANE stack (https://github.com/artificialio/sane). See jhliberty's answer below. This project automatically takes care of interfacing Ember/Sails and adds some cool features like auto-generating Ember/Sails models simultaneously using the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't speak for the "change what Ember expects" option, but I can say that this is precisely what blueprint overrides in Sails were invented for.  This would be a perfectly reasonable way to make your app Ember-compatible.

Also keep in mind that all of the CRUD blueprints use the `res.ok()` response to actually send data down to the client; if you like, you can just override that with your own `api/responses/ok.js`, perhaps using `req.url` to determine the resource that was being requested, and use that to wrap your JSON object in the manner that Ember expects.

Comment: Thanks! do you happen to know if someone maybe already wrote a set of blueprint overrides for Ember?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Sounds like an area ripe for contribution ;)

Answer (score 6):

There is a project called [Sane Stack](http://sanestack.com/) that uses a Sails blueprint to generate the appropriate setup for Ember and Sails, as well as provides a generator for creating resources in Ember and Sails at the same time.

> QUICKSTART
>
> `npm install -g sails sane-cli`
>
> `sane new project --docker` creates project with sails-disk and Docker. For production databases see Options.
>
> `sane generate resource user name:string age:number` to generate a new API on the backend and models on the frontend
>
> `sane up` to start the sails server on localhost:1337 as well as the ember dev server on localhost:4200.
>
> To work on your frontend-app you work as you would normally do with ember-cli on localhost:4200.
>
> You are now good to go.
>
> Note: If you use Docker, make sure you have fig installed. On Mac or Windows also boot2docker and for Linux see: https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/

Comment: Here's a link to the project on github: https://github.com/artificialio/sane. I'm currently using it to interface sails/ember and it works great.

Answer (score 3):

I just put up a few blueprint overrides that can be used as a starting point for using Sails as an Ember Data backend: https://github.com/mphasize/sails-ember-blueprints

Please let me know if you find a bug or have some suggestions for improvements!

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used ember in a few months, but the default blueprints responses are not compatible with ember-data.

Ember seems to be trying to conform to the [jsonapi](http://jsonapi.org/format/) spec.

Sails default blueprint responses do not.

That being said, it would be pretty easy to roll your own responses with sails.