# How to add a method for all controllers in Sails.js?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am trying to add a **method available for all controllers in sailsjs**, much like the blueprint methods are.
The method should also be exposed to a REST route (like /modelName/myBlueprintMethod).

How can I go about and do this?

I have seen lots of Qs for how to **override the blueprint** methods but what i need is **extend the blueprint**.

A little context.
What I want to achieve is to expose the schema of the model related to the controller to automate some front-end CMS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted a similar solution, although it would be a subset of your question: [Asked a question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25682116/sailsjs-setting-response-method-based-on-request-parameter)

One way to go about this (and there could be others) is:

Make a service, send it the parameters and use it in all controllers.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Altought is a little cleaner approach I would like and approach where no code is needed in the controller. So every controller bootstraps with the method(s).

Comment: I will keep looking and let you know when I find an answer. I am hopping @mikermcneil gives us some attention :D and enlighten us.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe a hook would be a possibility, but since sails doesn't offer some kind of plug-in system, I don't feel confortable adding code directly to the npm module since it is .gitignored. Check this [hook](https://github.com/lucasconstantino/sails-hooks-seeds) for seeding database as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I did mine as described here: [OVERRIDE CRUD BLUEPRINTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273789/crud-blueprint-overriding-in-sailsjs).

I created the blueprint hooks in `/api/blueprints/`...

Comment: Thanks. But, is there a way to share the blueprint method to all controllers without specifying each and all in the config/routes.js?. I found out there are plugin api on the road. I hope we can achieve this then in a simple more modular way. http://t.co/TGdMws2sIj