# Sailsjs: Setting response method based on request parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js, single-page-application

So I have been working on a `SPA` project using `Sailsjs`. The problem is:

When the first page loads, I use `res.view` or `res.render` in my controller. But, for subsequent requests, I dont want to use `res.view` or `res.render`, rather I'd like to use `res.json`.

Right now, I use the method:

`return req.param('json') ? res.json(myObj) : res.view('layout', myObj);`

This works, but I was looking for a more generic and abstract method in which my controller itself would know (on the basis of `req.param('json')`) whether to use `res.view` or `res.json` without me having to tell it explicitly.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `res.ok()` is for.

In the controller action below, `res.ok` will either display the **myAction.ejs** using `data` as the view locals, or respond with `data` as JSON, depending on how the request came in (i.e. via AJAX, sockets or a regular browser request):

```
module.exports = {

    myAction: function(req, res) {

       var data = {someKey: "someVal"};

       return res.ok(data);

    }

}
```

Internally, the `ok` response uses `req.wantsJSON` to determine what to do; it checks headers, looks for an `xhr` object and generally does its best to guess your intent.  `req.wantsJSON` is available for all requests (as is `req.isSocket`), so you can use them yourself as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read up on res.ok [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/responses/defaults/ok.js). Since I am making an SPA app that will render the first page from server, I will always have to provide the 'layout.ejs' argument, since any page can be the first page. Also, my json requests will either come through AJAX or socket. Will `req.wantsJSON` behave reliably ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify a layout unless you're using a layout template other than **views/layout.ejs**. As for `wantsJSON`, yes, it will return `true` in both those situations. You can check the code for it [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/f8870e796c22f5f9e39fb9d7c0047d73c82b157e/lib/hooks/request/qualifiers.js)

Comment: I have found that, if I do not provide a layout, then it does not take **views/layout.ejs** by default. Rather, it takes the view in the controller folder, by the name of the action. So, if I'm in UserController and profile action, then by default sails renders **user/profile.ejs**.

Comment: You're confusing layouts with views.  Rendering **user/profile.ejs** is exactly what `res.view` (which `res.ok` calls) is supposed to do.  The *layout* is a separate **.ejs** file which you can use as a template to wrap *around* your view--the specific view will be inserted at the `<%- body %>` tag in the layout file.  See the [default Sails **layout.ejs** file](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-views/blob/master/templates/layout.ejs) for reference--it contains the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags, so that your views don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of tinkering, I resolved this using a service.

I wrote a service (in **GlobalUtils.js**):

```
render: function (req, res, obj) {
    if(req.param('json')) {
        return res.json(obj);
    }
    else {
        return res.view('layout', obj);
    }
}
```

And I use this service in my controllers, like so:

`return GlobalUtils.render(req, res, myObj);`

But still, looking for a better method.