# Create a model instance with a collection property set in SailsJS

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I am working on a project using SailsJS as backend. In its waterline data model, I defined a model Abc. Abc has a property, images, which is a collection. Each value in images is an id of an instance of a different Image model.

When I post an object to '/abc', with images property of the object set to be a string containing ids of images, such as '1,2', the Abc instance creation process works, as shown by results of subsequent GET requests.

In current settings, when the 'POST /abc' process works, the newly created abc instance will be returned as server response.

```
POST /abc?property1=' '&property2=' '&images='1,2'...
```

server response:

```
{ id: 1000, property1=' ', property2=' ', ....}
```

However, server response does not contain populated images properties.

How can I request server to return populated images property for the newly created abc instance in its response?

Comment: sails usually does return you the populated relations by default, or let's say it returns the same response as when you do a `GET`. You can inspect the code for the default [`create` blueprint](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/tree/master/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions), and perhaps you can try [overriding it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273789/crud-blueprint-overriding-in-sailsjs).

Answer (score 0):

You're probably should define [`afterCreate` callback](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models.md#callbacks-on-create) in your model. It is invoked each time when you use `Model.create()` with newly created record as first parameter. You can specify there anything that you want your model to return when you create new record.