# Sails JS how does generated entity have create when controller is empty ?

Tags: sails.js

I got a basic question.

I'm trying out Sails (http://sailsjs.org/) and it has terminal commands to generate entity such as `User` entity:

```
sails generate api user
```

My question is, the UserController.js file shows:

```
/**
 * UserController
 *
 * @description :: Server-side logic for managing users
 * @help        :: See http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Controllers
 */

module.exports = {

};
```

How come when I access:

http://localhost:1337/user/create

It knows how to create a new User entity ? The controller clearly does not have a create action like this:

```
module.exports = {
    create: function(req, res) {
        // code to create new user
    }
};
```

So surely nothing should happen.

I did a bit of Symphony 2.0 PHP web framework and we needed to create those actions manually.

I'm confuzzled and impressed at the same time, any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the Sails.js world!

You have just discovered the **Blueprint API**.

When you lift your app, Sails will add generic actions to your controllers that have a model of the same name (to this day `find`, `findOne`, `create`, `update`, `destroy`, `populate`, `add` and `remove` actions exist implicitly). That's called **Blueprints actions**.

In addition, **Blueprints routes** can also be binded to your controllers' actions. Here is the list of those routes:

- **Blueprints RESTful routes**: automatically generated routes to expose a conventionnal REST API on top of `find`, `create`, `update`, and `destroy` actions

  - GET /post -> `PostController.find`
  - GET /post/:id -> `PostController.findOne`
  - POST /post -> `PostController.create`
  - PUT /post/:id -> `PostController.update`
  - DELETE /post/:id -> `PostController.destroy`
- **Blueprints shortcuts routes**: simple helpers to provide access to a controller's CRUD methods from your browser's URL bar

  - GET /user/create?name=joe -> `Post.create`
  - GET /user/update/1?name=mike -> `Post.update`
  - GET /user/destroy/1 -> `Post.destroy`
- **Blueprints actions routes**: automatically create routes for your custom controller actions

  - GET /group/count -> `Post.count`

Each of them can be deactivated in the `config/blueprints.js` file.

You can find more details on the [docs](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/blueprint-api).

Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273789/crud-blueprint-overriding-in-sails-js) if you want to redefine the blueprints actions.

Comment: I'm writing a little project [on GitHub](https://github.com/YannBertrand/SailsBasicViewsProject) if you want to take full advantage of the Blueprint API power