# sails.js blueprints override as hook

Tags: sails.js

A while back I asked how to override sails.js blueprints ([CRUD blueprint overriding in sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273789/crud-blueprint-overriding-in-sails-js))

With v0.11 of sails.js we now have blueprints (and they are awesome :)).

Is it possible to turn off the current blueprints and install a new version of them as a hook?
This issue comment (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/2173#issuecomment-54165548) from @sgress454 seems to indicate it is/was in the works, but I can't find anything more specific about it.

I know I can override by creating an api/blueprints folder, but it would be easier for my users to consume via an npm install.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this is possible.

It is actually what happens in Sails's core here : https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/tree/master/lib/hooks/blueprints
Default blueprints are loaded like an [Installable Hook](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/extending-sails/hooks/installable-hooks) would be.

You can just go ahead and copy that MIT licensed code and then replace the content of the `actions` directory with your own blueprints.
After that, update the object `BlueprintController` in `index.js` to make sure it points to your files.

Finally, all the magic happens in the `extendControllerMiddleware` method. You can see the code will go through each controller to inject your blueprints. The key point here is the replace the call to `_.defaults` with `_.assign` because your sails hook will want to overwrite defaults blueprints and not simply add them if they do not exist.