# Effectively using association population in SailsJS

Tags: sails.js

Association auto population is sexy during the early stages of the app development. Soon as the related models result in high number of associated records the api calls get a drastic performance hit. SailsJS provides a way to toggle this globally.

```
module.exports.blueprints.populate = true / false;
```

Ideal application would be to disable this option globally and load the related models on demand , is this possible ( Base use case would be how Laravel does things with Eager loading http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading ).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to override the blueprint configuration [per controller](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api) #/disabling-blueprints-on-a-per-controller-basis

> You may also override any of the settings from config/blueprints.js on a per-controller basis by defining a '_config' key in your controller defintion, and assigning it a configuration object with overrides for the settings in this file.

Try this in the controller where you want to activate populate:

```
module.exports = {
  _config: {
    populate: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah , but i am looking for more fine gained control. For an example , when I have multiple associated models , I want it to populate for a 1/2 rest calls depending on a query string ( For an example )

Comment: I think you can have a look at [this answer then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22273789/crud-blueprint-overriding-in-sails-js#answer-22274325)