# Sailsjs overwrite blueprint method for one model

Tags: sails.js

I have a Sails API where a certain model (Role) needs to return data different to the default. I have written a method in the controller to send back the data I want, but if I set up a route in `config/routes.js` like so:

```
'GET /role/:id': 'RoleController.readRole'
```

It takes precedence over other routes set up like
`http://localhost:1337/role/count/`
or `http://localhost:1337/role?limit=10&populate=user&sort=createdAt+DESC`

How can I overwrite the findOne method only for the Role model and leave everything else the same? As far as I can see Sails only lets me overwrite a blueprint for all models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24877350/218312) you can override methods if you name a method the same in your controller, so changing `readRole` to `findOne` solved my problem.